# Getting the Server.serve status code using node-static in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-static

I'm trying to write some of the node-static example code in Typescript and I'm getting the error

> Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Error'

Here is my code with the error

```
import * as server from 'node-static';
import * as http from "http"

var fileServer = new server.Server('./images');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        var callback: server.Callback;
        callback = function (e: Error) {
            if (e && (e.status === 404)) { // Error in this line 
                fileServer.serveFile('/not-found.html', 404, {}, request, response);
            }
        };
        fileServer.serve(request, response, callback)
    }).resume();
}).listen(8080);
```

Error has type string and is the stacktrace, so the reason for the typescript error is clear.
My question is how to get the status code.

The original JavaScript code is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-static#serving-specific-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `@types` for `node-static` is wrong. [Link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node-static/index.d.ts#L15)

Especially because the `Callback` is a function that can also have a `res` object.

You can always fallback to `any`